# How to change hyperlinks of images in Work Item in TFS

Tags: image, tfs, hyperlink

Image can be inserted into Details section of Work Item in TFS using Insert Image button. Is it possible to change final hyperlink to image ?

Issue is that we are using VPN in order to access TFS and hyperlinks to images do not have the full path with the domain that we need to see it directly in the WI itself.
If is possible to do some configuration changes for this ?

Comment: Does it occur without VPN connection? The issue looks like this one: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/766722/issues-with-displaying-pictures-embedded-into-work-item-description-via-vs2012

Answer (score 0):

For the local image, now within TFS under the "History" tab where you're inserting your image. It will automatically displays as an image directly. *PS: I'm using VS2015*

[image]

For the online image, it's impossible now. You can only view the hyperlinks or save it as local then update it. Please refer this user voice: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2037677-copy-and-paste-screenshots-into-work-items

Comment: it is a local image but we are using VPN and cannot see it. There is a blank space as a placeholder and I can right-click and in properties I see that the link is missing a domain name that I need to add. So for now I copy link and adjust in browser. I want to know if I can adjust local images links in WI.

Comment: Seems impossible. What's the phenomenon of if you disable VPN? Could you see the image directly in the history dialog? And for a workaround ,you can add the image as an attachments. If so, could you open the attachments link  with VPN successful.